# Jquery UI Datepicker Calendar Not Working As Expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a page with a list of hotel rooms. Against each room there is a link to open an availability calendar. I have found that if I click on the first room, the calendar shows properly. But links lower down the list open the file but not the calendar. If I start at the bottom and work upwards, they all open correctly.

In very simplified form, this is the page with the list:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NONE">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<br><br>
<a href="javascript:;" class="click" data-roomid="1133">1133</a>
<br><br>
<div class="hiddencal" data-roomid="1133" style="height:250px"></div>
<a href="javascript:;" class="click" data-roomid="1134">1134</a>
<br><br>
<div class="hiddencal" data-roomid="1134" style="height:250px"></div>
<a href="javascript:;" class="click" data-roomid="1135">1135</a>
<br><br>
<div class="hiddencal" data-roomid="1135" style="height:250px"></div>
<a href="javascript:;" class="click" data-roomid="1136">1136</a>
<br><br>
<div class="hiddencal" data-roomid="1136" style="height:250px"></div>
<br><br>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.click").on('click', function() {
        var roomid = $(this).attr("data-roomid");
        $(".hiddencal[data-roomid='" + roomid + "']").load("testcalendar.php?hid=encinas&room_id=" + roomid + "&month=06&year=2019");
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the file with the calendar on it:

```
<?php 
//Select database
require_once('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
mysqli_select_db(XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX);
mysqli_set_charset(XXXXXXXXXXXXX);

// Get the hid which is passed from previous page
if (isset($_REQUEST['hid'])) {
    $hid=$_REQUEST['hid'];
}

// Get the room_id which is passed from previous page
if (isset($_REQUEST['room_id'])) {
    $room_id=$_REQUEST['room_id'];
}

// Get the month and year passed from previous page
if (isset($_REQUEST['month'])) {
    $month=$_REQUEST['month'];
}
if (isset($_REQUEST['year'])) {
    $year=$_REQUEST['year'];
}

$setdate = $year."-".$month."-01";

$firstmonth = $month - 2;
if($firstmonth==0) {
    $firstmonth=12;
    $year=$year-1;
}
if($firstmonth==-1) {
    $firstmonth=11;
    $year=$year-1;
}
$firstdate = $year."-".$firstmonth."-01";
$lastdate=date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$firstdate +300 day"));

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NONE">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jquery-ui.min.css">

</head>

<body>
<h5>Test Calendar - <?php echo $room_id ?></h5>
<div id="calendar"></div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {

    function avail(date) {
       return true;
    }

    $('#calendar').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: avail, 
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        defaultDate: '<?php echo $setdate ?>',
        minDate: '<?php echo $firstdate ?>',
        maxDate: '<?php echo $lastdate ?>',
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        stepMonths: 1,
        showOtherMonths: true
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

On the occasions when the calendar fails, the heading ("Test Calendar - 1136") is displayed, so I know I am getting to that file OK. Presumably therefore, it is something in the script at the end, but I just can't see the problem.

Comment: I think I see what you're trying to do and I don't know that it's a good method. As I see it, you have an icon and when the User clicks it, a calendar should appear showing dates that are available for reservation. Currently, you're trying to load new HTML from PHP. When you navigate to the load target directly, does it load properly? I would consider having an AJAX call to your PHP that returns JSON or an array of data that a waiting datepicker can use in `beforeShowDate`. Or it can call the PHP each time and check a single date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lay in testcalendar.php, which was the file containing the calendar. It included a . Although I know that an id must be unique, I didn't realise that I was breaking that rule when I inserted the file multiple times into a parent file. Especially as it was only a problem when working down the page and not when going up.

The solution was to change the div to

```
<div id="calendar<?php echo $room_id ?>">
```

and the corresponding line of jquery to

```
$('#calendar<?php echo $room_id ?>').datepicker({
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example method you may want to consider.

```js
$(function() {
  function checkDate(rId, dObj) {
    var dStr = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", dObj);
    $.get("testcalendar.php", {
      hid: "encinas",
      room_id: rId,
      date: dStr
    }, function(result) {
      if (result) {
        return result;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    });
    return true;
  }
  $(".room-cal").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    stepMonths: 1,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    minDate: "+1d",
    maxDate: "+300d",
    beforeShowDay: function(dt) {
      var r = $(this).parent().parent();
      var a = checkDate(r.data("room-id"), dt);
      return [a, (a ? "available" : "booked")];
    }
  });
  $(".room-avail").on("click", function() {
    var cal = $(".room-cal", this);
    cal.datepicker("show");
  });
});
```

```css
.room {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: .75em;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.room-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18pt;
}

.room-avail {
  background: #cfcfcf;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: .4em .2em;
  margin-right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.room-cal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="room" data-room-id="1133">
  <div class="room-avail" title="Click to see Availiblity"><input type="text" class="room-cal" /><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-calendar"></span> Date Availible</div>
  <div class="room-title">2 Twins - 1133</div>
  <div class="room-desc">Ocean View</div>
</div>
<div class="room" data-room-id="1134">
  <div class="room-avail" title="Click to see Availiblity"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-calendar"></span> Date Availible</div>
  <div class="room-title">2 Twins - 1134</div>
  <div class="room-desc">First Floor</div>
</div>
<div class="room" data-room-id="1135">
  <div class="room-avail" title="Click to see Availiblity"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-calendar"></span> Date Availible</div>
  <div class="room-title">2 Twins - 1135</div>
  <div class="room-desc">Ocean View</div>
</div>
<div class="room" data-room-id="1136">
  <div class="room-avail" title="Click to see Availiblity"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-calendar"></span> Date Availible</div>
  <div class="room-title">2 Twins - 1136</div>
  <div class="room-desc">First Floor</div>
</div>
```

In PHP, you might have something like:

```
<?php
// check-date.php

require_once('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
mysqli_select_db(XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX);
mysqli_set_charset(XXXXXXXXXXXXX);

if (isset($_GET['hid'])) {
    $hid=$_GET['hid'];
}

if (isset($_GET['room_id'])) {
    $room_id=$_GET['room_id'];
}

if (isset($_GET['date'])) {
    $date=$_GET['month'];
}

$sql = "SELECT avail FROM $hid WHERE room = $room_id AND date = $date LIMIT 1;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$avail = (mysqli_num_rows($result) ? false : true);

echo $avail;
?>
```

This sets up each datepicker in the client and when `beforeShowDay` runs, it will check each day (35 days) for availability via a GET command to a PHP Script. The PHP Script will return `true` or `false` if the room is available on that day. The datepicker will shows the calendar from tomorrow forward. Only days that are available will be selectable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Twisty. That seemed to involve tearing up everything I had done and starting again, and I was having difficulty understanding your code. So I dug around some more and found a solution that was a simple change to my existing code. Perhaps it's obvious to others, but it wasn't obvious to me that I was getting multiple instances of the same id, and that was causing the problem.

Comment: @TrapezeArtist Ok, I see how that can be an issue.